# How to make grunt support runtime option in register config?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm intend to run the code:

```
grunt.registerTask('build', ['compile-handlebars:build --env=prod','copy','uglify','cssmin']);
```

But it doesn't work and report an error:

```
"Warning: Required config property "compile-handlebars.build --env=prod" missing."
```

Comment: When registering tasks you *only* specify the *task names* as an array, no option as if you're running it from command line. I'd say since you want to compile the templates in production mode you shoukd run your whole build using `grunt build --env=prod`. Another option is to configure a `compile-handlebars` task named "build-prod" passing the environment option to the Grunt config (JSON) (this is only possible if that task accepts such a config).

Comment: @try-catch-finally Thanks, you solve my problem!